# Finding magnitudes of tensions

Tags: vectors

This question considers two different methods of securing a lamp of mass $0.5 kg$ during a camping trip.

You should model the lamp as a particle.

In the first method, the lamp is suspended by two ropes from a horizontal rod at the top of the tent. At the lamp, the angle between the two ropes is 85◦. The left-hand rope makes an angle of 55◦ with the rod, and the right-hand rope makes an angle of 40◦ with the rod.

Calculate the magnitude (in newtons) of the tension in each rope.

Working so far:

[image: This shows force diagram and directions for unit vectors.]

$$\vec{S}= -Scos(55^{\circ})\vec{i} + Ssin(55^{\circ}) \vec{j}$$

$$\vec{S} = - Ssin\frac{7\pi}{36} \vec{i} + Scos\frac{7\pi}{36} \vec{j}$$

doing the same with $\vec{T}$ gives:

$$\vec{T} = Tcos\frac{2\pi}{9} \vec{i}+Tsin\frac{2\pi}{9}\vec{j}$$

$$\vec{W}= -0.5g\vec{j}$$

$$\vec{T} +\vec{S}+\vec{W} = \vec{0}$$

getting the i's and j's together...

$$(Tcos\frac{2\pi}{9} - Ssin\frac{7\pi}{36})\vec{i} + (Tsin\frac{2\pi}{9} + Scos \frac{7\pi}{36})\vec{j} = \vec{0}$$

From here i intended to solve the two equations simultaneously by setting both equal to 0:

$$(Tcos\frac{2\pi}{9} - Ssin\frac{7\pi}{36}) = 0$$

$$ (Tsin\frac{2\pi}{9} + Scos \frac{7\pi}{36})= 0 $$

when I solve this I get both $T$ and $S$ = $0$

I'm not sure where I have gone wrong. Please help.

Comment: You forgot the $\vec{W}$ when getting the $i'$'s and $j$'s together, I think.